# How to avoid cline overwride when using cellcolor?

Tags: tables, color, tabularx, pgfplotstable, cellcolor

The cline between the colored cells 1 and 2 in the example below has been overridden by the cellcolor command. 
I was wondering whether there exists a way to make the line separating these two cells on top of the yellow color. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Hartmut Helmut

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
     Days  & 3 & 6 & 9 & 12 & 15 & 18 \\
     \hline\hline
     \multirow{2}{*}{Project} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\cellcolor{yellow} 1} & & \\
     \cline{2-7}
  & & & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\cellcolor{yellow} 2}  \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: please see the `colortbl` package documentation. `\cline` is explicitly _not_ supported. You could use `\hhline` from the `hhline` package instead.

Comment: @Schweinebacke The question you referred to deals with \columncolor while here I have cellcolor

Comment: @HartmutHelmut these are the same thing (more or less)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `hhline`. B.t.w., don't nest your `table` environment in `center`, as it adds an unwanted supplementary vertical spacing. Use the directive `\centering` instead.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow, hhline}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hhline{*{7}{-}}
    Days & 3 & 6 & 9 & 12 & 15 & 18 \\
    \hhline{*{7}{:=}:}
    \multirow{2}{*}{Project} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\cellcolor{yellow} 1} & & \\
    \hhline{|~|------|}
                             & & & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\cellcolor{yellow} 2} \\
    \hhline{*{7}{-}}
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In my case, if the cell "Project" has a color, hhline cuts it with a white line. Is that avoidable?